# NSSortDescriptor incorrectly sort date and strings, which are properties of custom class, but correctly sort integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, xcode6, nssortdescriptor

I've created simple class Student with properties

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString* firstname;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString* lastname;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSDate* dateOfBirth;
@property (assign,nonatomic) NSInteger index;
```

After that, I created any objects of this class, gave it firstname, lastname, date and index, add all of them to self.InitialStudentsArray. And start sorting by dateOfBirth:

```
NSSortDescriptor* descriptorDate=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"dateOfBirth" ascending:YES];
NSArray* descArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptorDate, nil];
[self.InitialStudentsArray sortUsingDescriptors:descArray];
```

So, the result is strange. Array before sorting and after sorting have different items order, but not sorted at all by date.

```
before sort (
    "46 Alex  Dupel 25 10 1991",
    "236 Ivan  Evstegneev 20 09 1980",
    "179 Hugo  Igonin 03 02 1992",
    "189 Alexey  Boronenko 06 11 1978" ) 


after sort (
    "236 Ivan  Evstegneev 20 09 1980",
    "179 Hugo  Igonin 03 02 1992",
    "189 Alexey  Boronenko 06 11 1978",
    "46 Alex  Dupel 25 10 1991" )
```

The same thing with firstname and lastname (even if use selectors:

```
NSSortDescriptor* descriptorLastname=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"lastname" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

It's only work for property "index",which is NSInteger.

What I've done else, I created array only with dates from student.dateOfBirth and sorted it with keyname self. And it works! Another experiment - I created array of dictionaries with key "dateOfBirth" and sorted it by key name @"dateOfBirth" and it also works!

I know about other methods live sortUsingComparator, but why this method doesn't work on date and strings in properties??

---

Upd
Oh, guys, it's my mistake. I appreciate all of your answers, they pushed me to place, where to search mistake. And when I found it, I felt very ashamed. Absolutly stupid mistake. If you are interested in, I used this way to initialize student:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.firstname=[self getFirstname];
        self.lastname=[self getLastname];
        self.dateOfBirth=[self getDateOfBirth];
    }
    return self;
}
-(NSString*) getFirstname {//some code...arrayOfFirstames...name=arc4random()...}
```

I.e. I occasionally redefine getter for setting property. All three. So, when I was sorting array everytime new values was taken.
Thank you.

Comment: They appear to be sorted by `firstname` with descending order. You should change your date format if you want it to sort correctly using string comparison. Instead of "DD MM YYYY" use "YYYY MM DD".

Comment: If you use `[descriptorDate compareObject:self.InitialStudentsArray[0] toObject:self.InitialStudensArray[1]]`, does it return the correct value?

Comment: @Ian MacDonald, i've tried it and it may return correct value and may return incorrect. Like it doesn't depend on items. Like it depends on something else..

Comment: You will have something else wrong. Can you show the accessors for 'InitialStudentsArray' for example?

Comment: @Ian MacDonald, about your first note. It's just an accident, that they sorted by firstname with des order. In other times it doesn't. I want to sort date like NSDate and string like NSString.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Here it is. There is no something special.
`self.InitialStudentsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        Student* student=[[Student alloc]init];
        [self.InitialStudentsArray addObject:student]; 
    }`

Comment: This is not the accessor. Is it synthesized? Can't find a property.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad. Just a property `@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray* InitialStudentsArray;` Nothing else.

Comment: Rather than your "before sort" and "after sort" snippets (which are maybe using a custom `-description` method on the `Student` class?), try logging `[self.InitialStudentsArray valueForKey:@"dateOfBirth"]` before and after.

Comment: BTW: Your accessors are an infringement of the naming rules. You should read something about naming in Objective-C otherwise you will get problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have wrong another thing, SortDescriptors work fine with strings, here an example:

```
NSArray *people = @[@{@"name": @"Ivan"},@{@"name": @"Hugo"},@{@"name": @"Alexey"},@{@"name": @"Alex"}];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorts = @[sort];
NSArray *orderedArray = [people sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sorts];
NSLog(@"Show orderedArray: %@",[orderedArray description]);
```

Exit in console:

```
2014-11-14 20:19:45.377 pro[1366:60b] Show orderedArray: (
    {
    name = Alex;
},
    {
    name = Alexey;
},
    {
    name = Hugo;
},
    {
    name = Ivan;
}
)
```

I think it´s good idea to log your array before and after the sortedArrayUsingDescriptor methods.

Hi again. I´ve done the same again, with a Custom Class this is the header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CustomClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end
```

The implementation (.m) is blank, and again I´ve done:

```
CustomClass *ivan = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
ivan.name = @"Ivan";

CustomClass *hugo = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
hugo.name = @"Hugo";

CustomClass *alexey = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
alexey.name = @"Alexey";

CustomClass *alex = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
alex.name = @"Alex";


NSArray *people = @[ivan,hugo,alexey,alex];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorts = @[sort];
NSArray *orderedArray = [people sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sorts];
 NSLog(@"Show orderedArray:");
for (CustomClass *people in orderedArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@\n",people.name);
}
```

And again, the exit console is:

```
 2014-11-14 22:38:13.297 pro[1406:147113] Show orderedArray:
 2014-11-14 22:38:13.298 pro[1406:147113] Alex
 2014-11-14 22:38:13.298 pro[1406:147113] Alexey
 2014-11-14 22:38:13.298 pro[1406:147113] Hugo
 2014-11-14 22:38:13.298 pro[1406:147113] Ivan
```

There isn´t any problem with sortDescriptors and property. Best

Comment: I confirm, that it works fine with strings in your example, and i wrote about it - if it's array of dictionaries - no problem. But if string or date is property of my own class, and array consist of object of that class, so it doesn't work.

Comment: yea, it's working! Thank you for this code. It helps a lot. I update post and tell where I was wrong)